# How can I see if any of my nested models have a specific attribute in a `where` statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

My statement..

```
Object.joins(:child_objects).where("child_objects.type != 'Magical!'").group(:id)
```

This will still return `Object`'s that have a `child_object` with a type equal to `Magical!`..

How can I exclusively return *only* Objects that do not have a child_object type of Magical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-select (I use 'classical' `Product <= LineItem => Order` model set) and `NOT IN`:

```
jdoe_products = Product.joins(:orders).where(orders: {name: 'jdoe'})
Product.where('id NOT IN (%s)' % jdoe_products.select(:id).to_sql)
```

Produces:

```
  Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (id NOT IN (SE
LECT "products"."id" FROM "products" INNER JOIN "line_items" ON "line_items"."pr
oduct_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "line_items".
"order_id" WHERE "orders"."name" = 'jdoe'))
```

Comment: Ah you fancy man you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The real question is.. is that as light as it gets?